# How do you Switch User?

Tags: vb.net, switch-user

We're upgrading some work PC's to Windows 8, so for those users that fear change I've written a small helper app to help them log off (to keep them away from Metro, where possible).

The app works just fine except that I cannot find out how to Switch User. I've looked at all the switches for the `shutdown` command (`shutdown -?`) but I cannot find any reference to it there.

Can anybody please shed some light on how I achieve this? Thanks.

```
Private Sub Event_Click(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim ActionButton As String = Sender.Name

    Select Case ActionButton

        Case "ShutdownButton" : Process.Start("ShutDown", "/s /t 0") : Exit Select
        Case "RestartButton" : Process.Start("ShutDown", "/r") : Exit Select
        Case "LockButton" : LockWorkStation() : Exit Select
        'Case "SwitchUserButton" : ??? : Exit Select
        Case "LogOutButton" : System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ShutDown", "/l") : Exit Select
        Case "HibernateButton" : System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ShutDown", "/h") : Exit Select

    End Select

    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Referencing http://www.guidingtech.com/14991/faster-better-switch-user-windows-7-8/
and
http://www.nextofwindows.com/windows-7-8-quick-tip-how-to-switch-user-from-a-command-line/?ModPagespeed=noscript

I believe the most fastest way is to Win>L and press "Switch User", though you can't do the second step programatically... there's no real command to switch user.